# Optimise HM Land Registry SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

I got the following query that successfully extracts house price index data from the UK land registry (https://api.triplydb.com/s/BIN1LSLxO):

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# House price index for aa  within a given date range
SELECT *
{
?region ukhpi:refPeriodStart ?date ;
        ukhpi:refRegion ?refRegion .
  
?refRegion rdfs:label ?regionLabel ;
           
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePrice ?averagePrice }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceCash ?averagePriceCash }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceDetached   ?averagePriceDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceExistingProperty ?averagePriceExistingProperty }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceFirstTimeBuyer  ?averagePriceFirstTimeBuyer }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceFlatMaisonette ?averagePriceFlatMaisonette }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceFormerOwnerOccupier    ?averagePriceFormerOwnerOccupier }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceMortgage   ?averagePriceMortgage }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceNewBuild   ?averagePriceNewBuild }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceSemiDetached   ?averagePriceSemiDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:averagePriceTerraced   ?averagePriceTerraced }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndex    ?housePriceIndex }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexCash    ?housePriceIndexCash }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexDetached    ?housePriceIndexDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexExistingProperty    ?housePriceIndexExistingProperty }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexFirstTimeBuyer  ?housePriceIndexFirstTimeBuyer }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexFlatMaisonette  ?housePriceIndexFlatMaisonette }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexFormerOwnerOccupier ?housePriceIndexFormerOwnerOccupier }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexMortgage    ?housePriceIndexMortgage }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexNewBuild    ?housePriceIndexNewBuild }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexSemiDetached    ?housePriceIndexSemiDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:housePriceIndexTerraced    ?housePriceIndexTerraced }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChange ?percentageAnnualChange }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeCash ?percentageAnnualChangeCash }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeDetached ?percentageAnnualChangeDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeExistingProperty ?percentageAnnualChangeExistingProperty }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeFirstTimeBuyer   ?percentageAnnualChangeFirstTimeBuyer }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeFlatMaisonette   ?percentageAnnualChangeFlatMaisonette }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeFormerOwnerOccupier ?percentageAnnualChangeFormerOwnerOccupier }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeMortgage ?percentageAnnualChangeMortgage }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeNewBuild ?percentageAnnualChangeNewBuild }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeSemiDetached ?percentageAnnualChangeSemiDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageAnnualChangeTerraced ?percentageAnnualChangeTerraced }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChange   ?percentageChange }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeCash   ?percentageChangeCash }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeDetached   ?percentageChangeDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeExistingProperty   ?percentageChangeExistingProperty }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeFirstTimeBuyer ?percentageChangeFirstTimeBuyer }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeFlatMaisonette ?percentageChangeFlatMaisonette }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeFormerOwnerOccupier    ?percentageChangeFormerOwnerOccupier }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeMortgage   ?percentageChangeMortgage }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeNewBuild   ?percentageChangeNewBuild }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeSemiDetached   ?percentageChangeSemiDetached }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:percentageChangeTerraced   ?percentageChangeTerraced }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:refMonth   ?refMonth }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:refPeriodDuration  ?refPeriodDuration }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:refPeriodStart ?refPeriodStart }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:salesVolume    ?salesVolume }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:salesVolumeCash    ?salesVolumeCash }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:salesVolumeExistingProperty    ?salesVolumeExistingProperty }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:salesVolumeMortgage    ?salesVolumeMortgage }
OPTIONAL { ?region ukhpi:salesVolumeNewBuild ?salesVolumeNewBuild }

FILTER (
?date > "2008-12-31"^^xsd:date &&
?date < "2019-03-01"^^xsd:date &&
contains (lcase(str(?refRegion)),"nottingham")
) 
}
```

However, this suffers of a problem: if I would like to search for `Chester`, I got back `Manchster`, `Colchester` among the others.
The best way would be to lookup for the right region name, in this case `Cheshire West and Chester` on Ordnance Survey, and filter by that name. However, I have no idea how to do it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: the big question is, what is an "outcode"? And then, does this information exist in the dataset? If so, which property is used for it, or how is it encoded?

Comment: I have changed the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: ok, but that's a common problem which can't be solved automatically. In a first step, you have to find the correct entity for a string - this indeed can't be solved fully automatically because there might be multiple entities matching a string and in your case, you even don't know the exact string, thus, you can only apply for substring resp. some kind of similarity matching. If you don't care about this step, just getting all entities matching a string in a first step is easy, provide it to the user who decides on which entity exactly was meant.

Comment: The second step indeed is trivial, just provide the entity URI as inline data to the query.